# CSS not getting applied to the form elements in .erb

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to apply css to a form in .erb and it doesnt seem to be working.

**CSS**

```
.submit-form{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
    font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #888;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
    border:1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
```

**HTML**

```
h1>Submit page </h1>
    <div class="submit-form">
    <%= simple_form_for Post.new do |f| %> 
       <%= f.input :title  %>
        <%= f.input :blurb %> 
       <%= f.input :funding_goal %>
       <%= f.input :funding_duration %>   
      <%= f.button :submit %>  
    <% end %> 
    </div>
```

this is the code from the application.css file

```
.hidden
{
  display: none;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.simple_form label {  
  float: left;  
  width: 100px;  
  text-align: right;  
  margin: 2px 10px;  
}  

.simple_form div.input {  
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
}  

.simple_form div.boolean, .simple_form input[type='submit'] {  
  margin-left: 120px;  
}  

.simple_form div.boolean label {  
  float: none;  
  margin: 0;  
}
```

I am wondering if i need to add the my sbmit.css.scss to appplication.css file

main.css

```
@import "variables";
@import "primitives";
@import "header";
@import "footer";

@import "homepage";
@import "share";
@import "checkout";
```

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/mzfmxsd8/3/

Comment: Have you included your `submit.css.scss` in your `application.css`?? Check in the browser styles are being applied??

Comment: Uandl: I dont have submit.css.scss in application.css file.i dont have any css file mentioned in application.css file but they are all working fine .i have updated the post with code of my application.css file

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the styles are not applied to the `form` element, that's because you are not applying it to the `form` element but instead to a `div` element. To add the class to the `form` element:

```
...
simple_form_for Post.new, class: "submit-form" do |f|
...
```

Comment: @user3543449 in the `.erb` file containing the form.

Comment: It gives me a unknown attribute: html error if i include this the .erb file of the form

Answer (score 1):

First try to add css in .erb file using  tag like below:

```
 <style>

 .submit-form{
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     max-width: 500px;
     background: #F7F7F7;
     padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
     font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     color: #888;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
     border:1px solid #E4E4E4; }

 </style>
```

If it works fine try to put the css in application.css(or css file which you have mentioned in layout)and check.

Comment: It works fine when put it in the .erb file but it doenst work fine when i put it in the css file

Comment: Have you included your css file name in application layout file?

Comment: No.I updated the post with the content of my application.css file.how do i add my css file to application layout file

Comment: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'%> like this u can include your css file name using stylesheet_link_tag (put the code in application layout)

Comment: I have <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'%> already in my application layout file.Should i add <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'submit'%> to its .erb file?

Comment: if you defined css for .submit-form in separate file you should include that file name in application layout using stylesheet_link_tag

Comment: I added <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'submit'%> to application layout (application.html.erb) but it didnt make any differecne

Comment: You can do one thing...check in browser whether that class has css or not using firebug.

Answer (score 0):

try by putting class in `form` tag in your erb file..

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'%>
<%= simple_form_for Post.new ,:html=>{:class => 'submit-form'} do |f| %>
```

put this in `application.css` file under **app/assets/stylesheets/**

```
 .submit-form{
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     max-width: 500px;
     background: #F7F7F7;
     padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
     font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     color: #888;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
     border:1px solid #E4E4E4; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you an answer which *should* work, try this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import "variables";
@import "primitives";
@import "header";
@import "footer";
@import "submit";

@import "homepage";
@import "share";
@import "checkout";

#app/assets/stylesheets/submit.css.scss
.submit-form { 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
    font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #888;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
    border:1px solid #E4E4E4;
}

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>

#app/views/controller/form.html.erb
<div class="submit-form">
   ...
</div>
```

If you apply the above code to your application, it should work for you, regardless of any dependencies etc in your app.

---

**Asset Pipeline**

To give you a clearer definition of how this works - you need to consider the role of the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) in Rails apps - this will cure all your future CSS woes.

When you run a Rails app, you basically have to "modularize" the application to ensure that it's able to run in the most efficient way possible. This means keeping your `views`, `controllers`, `models` and `assets` separate.

Because Rails is an [MVC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you don't have a "logical" flow as many programmers are used to. Instead, you have an object-orientated flow, which firmly places your *assets* to the side of the main "bulk" of the processing.

To make your assets work, therefore, you basically need to have them included in your layout. When they're included in the layout, it's up to you to ensure you have included the various dependent asset files you may need, allowing you to create & call the various classes as you require, as demonstrated above